# Remove dakuten/handakuten in Java (aka ten-ten, ぱ→は)

Tags: java, converters, diacritics, cjk, unicode-string

Many Japanese hiragana and kana have a dakuten and a handakuten variant.
Example: は becomes ば or ぱ (notice the ゛ and ゜ parts)

**Question**: How to remove these from a String, in Java?

For instance, I want `はばぱハバパ1aあア亜` to become `はははハハハ1aあア亜`.

Performance is important.

*Context: Matching content with a legacy system.*

Answer (score 4):

Characters with (han)dakuten can be decomposed into the base kana and a combining mark, Java has the `Normalizer` class for that in `java.text`.

```
String decomposed = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

Then the combining (han)dakuten marks can be removed with `replace` or `replaceAll`, for example

```
String noVoicingMarks = decomposed.replace("\u3099", "").replace("\u309A", "");
```

Or (a bit faster in my tests)

```
String noVoicingMarks = decomposed.replaceAll("\u3099|\u309A", "");
```

Comment: Should I maybe "recompose" the String afterwards? For instance, a String that does contain (han)dakutens should stay the same, even if it has other special accents. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul perhaps, it should *look* the same whether decomposed or not though. If necessary you can compose them back with the normalization form C, so NFC

Comment: That's probably the problem I am having right now. I am trying to match the resulting String with a constant String, they look exactly the same but their hexdump is different. So `String recomposed = Normalizer.normalize(noVoicingMarks, Normalizer.Form.NFC);` I guess?